# Postgres Db Table name is encoded using the NGSIToPostgreSQL processor from Fiware Draco

Tags: fiware

### Context

We have some data from sensors which is published on Firware Orion. We'd like to visualize the data in the Fiware CKAN Open Data Portal using Fiware Draco. At this moment the Draco (Nifi with NGSI extension) creats a table in the PostGres public namespace with an encoded name. This is an issue because the CKAN portal requires a valid guid as table name.

#### Nifi template config

The image below gives a high lever overview of the flow
[nifi template config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GoI0.png)
The update attributes processor configures the id of the resource in the CKAN datastore:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEVNd.png)

#### The id of the resource in the CKAN db

A resource created in the CKAN stores some metadata in the CKAN db. The id of this metadata has to be equal to the tablename in the datastore db.
Which is an issue at the moment because the NGSIToPostgreSQL processor encodes the tablename.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnxiX.png)

I already tried to disable the encoding. This is not a solution because data updates will fail throwing following issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBOzD.png)

Comment: Please can you tell me if when you disable the encoding after you receive the first notification?, I mean the table is already created?, Can you change the fiware service to a value different than public and disable the encoding and see if the table is created?

Comment: Also, can you try to including / in the fiware-servicepath?. I see that when you disable the encoding the table name try to be created using the fiware service path but the error shows that the first "c" of that field is removed, this is not the expected behavior. Please try to use / in the service path and tell me if the problem is solved

Comment: 1. I can't create the table first because I have to specify all the colums. This is one of the most usefull features of the NGSIToProgreSQL processor.
2. I can't test this together with step 1 because I can't create the table. If I add the slash at the start it will also be encoded, as x002